# R splitting cells with complex pattern strings

Tags: r, data-manipulation, string-matching

I am web-scraping a website  (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) to build up a dataset out of it.

`

```
  > str(result)
  $ title   : chr [1:4007]
  $ authors : chr [1:4007]
  $ cite    : chr [1:4007]
  $ PMID    : chr [1:4007]   
  $ synopsis: chr [1:4007]
  $ link    : chr [1:4007]
  $ abstract: chr [1:4007] `
```

[image]
[image]

```
          title                                           authors cite PMID  synop…¹ link  abstr…
        1 Food insecurity in baccalaureate nursing stude… Cocker… J Pr… 3386… METHOD… http… "Backg…
        2 Household food insecurity and educational outc… Masa R… Publ… 3271… We mea… http… "Objec…
        3 Food Insecurity and Food Label Comprehension a… Mansou… Nutr… 3437… Multiv… http… "Food …
        4 The Household Food Security and Feeding Patter… Omachi… Nutr… 3623… Childr… http… "Child…
        5 Food insecurity: Its prevalence and relationsh… Turnbu… J Hu… 3373… BACKGR… http… "Backg…
        6 Cross-sectional Analysis of Food Insecurity an… Estrel… West… 3535… METHOD… http… "Intro…
```

`
Among the various variables I am creating, there is one that is giving me trouble (resulut$cite): it includes various information that I have to split up into different columns in order to get a clear overview of the data I need. Here there is an example of some rows to show the difficulty I am facing. I have searched for similar issues but can't find anything fitting this.

```
      1. Public Health. 2021 Sep;198:332-339. doi: 10.1016/j.puhe.2021.07.032. Epub 2021 Sep 9. PMID: 34509858
      2. Public Health Nutr. 2021 Apr;24(6):1469-1477. doi: 10.1017/S1368980021000550. Epub 2021 Feb 9. PMID: 33557975
      3. Clin Nutr ESPEN. 2022 Dec;52:229-239. doi: 10.1016/j.clnesp.2022.11.005. Epub 2022 Nov 10. PMID: 36513458
```

Given this, I would like to split result$cite into multiple columns in order to attain what follows:

```
      Review         Date of publication   Page             doi         Reference            Epub          PMID   
      Public Health.         2021 Sep;      198:332-339.    10.1016   j.puhe.2021.07.032.    2021 Sep 9.   34509858
      Public Health Nutr.    2021 Apr;      24(6):1469-1477.10.1017 S1368980021000550.       2021 Feb 9.   33557975
      Clin Nutr ESPEN.       2022 Dec;      52:229-239.      10.1016 j.clnesp.2022.11.005.   2022 Nov 10.  36513458
```

The main problem for me is that the strings are not regular, hence I can't find a pattern to split the cells into different columns. Any idea?

Comment: Look into `extract` function from `tidyr`

Comment: Please check out the yet-again-updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you? (Since the OP will not provide data in **reproducible format** I've created a toy column `id`beside the `cite` column):

```
library(tidyverse)    
result %>%
  extract(cite, 
          into = c("Review","Date of publication","Page","doi","Reference","Epub","PMID"),
          regex = "\\d+\\. ([^.]+)\\. ([^;]+);([^.]+)\\. doi:([^/]+)/(\\S+)\\. Epub ([^.]+)\\. PMID: (\\d+)")
id             Review Date of publication            Page      doi            Reference        Epub
    1  1      Public Health            2021 Sep     198:332-339  10.1016   j.puhe.2021.07.032  2021 Sep 9
    2  2 Public Health Nutr            2021 Apr 24(6):1469-1477  10.1017    S1368980021000550  2021 Feb 9
    3  3    Clin Nutr ESPEN            2022 Dec      52:229-239  10.1016 j.clnesp.2022.11.005 2022 Nov 10
          PMID
    1 34509858
    2 33557975
    3 36513458
```

(**NB**: if there aren't leading numerics in `cite`, just remove this part from `regex`: `\\d+\\.` (with whitespace at the end!)

The way `extract` works may look difficult to parse but is actually quite simple. Essentially, you do two things: (i) you look at the strings and try and figure out how they are *patterned*, i.e., what rules they follow; (ii) in the `regex` argument you put everything you want to extract into distinct capture groups (`(...)`) and everything else remains outside of the capture groups.

Data (update #2):

```
result <- data.frame(id = 1:3,
                     cite = c("1. Public Health. 2021 Sep;198:332-339. doi: 10.1016/j.puhe.2021.07.032. Epub 2021 Sep 9. PMID: 34509858",
  "2. Public Health Nutr. 2021 Apr;24(6):1469-1477. doi: 10.1017/S1368980021000550. Epub 2021 Feb 9. PMID: 33557975",
  "3. Clin Nutr ESPEN. 2022 Dec;52:229-239. doi: 10.1016/j.clnesp.2022.11.005. Epub 2022 Nov 10. PMID: 36513458")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand the logic you are proposing, nevertheless there must be something (probably some syntax issue) that is impeding me to go onward for it split the columns but do not read the data hence I have: 

 `        `Review Date of publication Page  doi Reference Epub PMID
          1          <NA>                <NA> <NA> <NA>      <NA> <NA> <NA>
          2          <NA>                <NA> <NA> <NA>      <NA> <NA> <NA> `

Comment: Are your data like my data? Or are there any differences? My solution is tailored to the data as posted by you and re-posted by me in the answer as vector `x`.

Comment: Yes, the data are absolutely the same.
I am trying to figure it out, indeed. Of course, the variable includes hundred of other rows, though.

Comment: If you use *my* vector `x` do you still get `NA`? And, why not post more of your data **in reproducible format** (meaning ppl can just copy and paste it)?

Comment: I have converted my variable into your vector to include all the rows, then run the script
                                        `x <- result$cite`
and the result is actually `NA`

Comment: maybe the problem is the leading numerics (numbered list)

Comment: @tjebo Thanks for this; I've updated the data and the answer accordingly

Comment: So you have a dataframe called `result`and a column `cite`, right? Why not just post it **as such** (with its names and all) in reproducible format? You could do, for example, `head(dput(result))`. Would certainly make life easier for ppl willing to help you

Comment: well, clearer yes, a little. But what's so difficult about posting **reproducible data** (not code!)?

Comment: One remaining unclarity: are there or aren't there leading numerics in `cite`?

Comment: No, there are no leading numerics, in cite.

Comment: okay then delete the part indicated in the updated answer

Comment: does the solution now work for you?

Comment: No, it is giving me NA again. I don't understand what is going on since at the very first attempt it worked.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you any further as long as you don't follow my advice and use `dput(result)` and post the output in reproducibel format so I can work with the actual data.

Comment: The problem is that the data in their original format keep too much space busy, as you can see from the pictures attached.

Comment: Sorry mate that's not the way this works on SO. Post some actual data or leave it.